# How can i make it tidy?

Tags: html, css

[the work waiting to be done](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OfhQF.png)

I want them to be fixed on size; like a table without shared borders.

Here s my html and css codes:

```css
.leftsubstancelist {
  padding-top: 40px;
  border-top: 2px solid #003333;
  width: 39%;
  float: left;
}

.rightsubstancelist {
  padding-top: 40px;
  border-top: 2px solid #003333;
  width: 39%;
  float: right;
}

.leftsubstancelist figure {
  border: 3px solid #003333;
}

.rightsubstancelist figure {
  border: 3px solid #003333;
}

figure img {
  max-width: 80%
}
```

```html
<section class="leftsubstancelist">
  <figure>
    <img src="img/active_substance/vankomisin.png" alt="Vankomisin Hidroklorür" align="center">
    <figcaption>Vankomisin Hidroklorür</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <br>

  <figure>
    <img src="img/active_substance/imipenem_silastatin.png" alt="İmipenem / Silastatin" align="center">
    <figcaption>İmipenem / Silastatin</figcaption>
  </figure>

</section>

<section class="rightsubstancelist">

  <figure>
    <img src="img/active_substance/ertapenem.png" alt="Ertapenem" align="center">
    <figcaption>Ertapenem</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <br>

  <figure>
    <img src="img/active_substance/teikoplanin.png" alt="Teikoplanin" align="center">
    <figcaption>Teikoplanin</figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
```

I ve tried, display:box, align:center and some other related stuff but couldn't manage to tidy them up.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: PLUS: how can i make the images centered inside those "BOX"es? They stick on "up" and "left". Thank you!

Comment: I suggest, to not waste your time. In other words, use any CSS framework, such as [tag:twitter-bootstrap], [tag:foundation], etc

Comment: to center the images in the boxes, you can add `text-align: center;` to the `figure` css

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/).

When you want all rows to be of a continuous height, you could leave out `align-items` or set it to `stretch`. Otherwise you could use `align-items: flex-start` when you want them to have an individual height but rendered at top.

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

section {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
  /* Uncomment the following line, if the
     rows cell can have different heights */
  /* align-items: flex-start; */
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border-top: 2px solid #003333;
  padding: 20px;
}

figure {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  
  border: 3px solid #003333;
  width: calc( 50% - 40px );
  margin: 20px;
}

figure img {
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <figure>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x140" />
    <figcaption>Vankomisin Hidroklorür</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x160" />
    <figcaption>İmipenem / Silastatin</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x180" />
    <figcaption>Ertapenem</figcaption>
  </figure>

  <figure>
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/320x120" />
    <figcaption>Teikoplanin</figcaption>
  </figure>
</section>
```

Comment: Reading the comments, I updated my code so that the pictures are centered as well

Answer (score 1):

Try below:

```
<style>
.divSquare1{
width:45%; height:200px; margin:4px; border:1px solid black; float: left
}
.divSquare2{
width:45%; height:200px; margin:4px; border:1px solid black; float: right
}
.space{
width:5%;
}
</style>    

<div class="divSquare1">
<figure>
    <img src="img/active_substance/vankomisin.png" alt="Vankomisin Hidroklorür" align="center">
    <figcaption>Vankomisin Hidroklorür</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
<div class="divSquare2">
<figure>
    <img src="img/active_substance/imipenem_silastatin.png" alt="İmipenem / Silastatin" align="center">
    <figcaption>İmipenem / Silastatin</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
<div style='clear:both' class="space"></div>
<div class="divSquare1">
<figure>
    <img src="img/active_substance/ertapenem.png" alt="Ertapenem" align="center">
    <figcaption>Ertapenem</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
<div class="divSquare2">
<figure>
    <img src="img/active_substance/teikoplanin.png" alt="Teikoplanin"   align="center">
    <figcaption>Teikoplanin</figcaption>
</figure>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Set a static height for your figure element. This will make them all have the same height and spacing. I believe this will solve your issue but your question was vague.

```
figure {
  height: 150px;
}
```

Comment: That's a good answer but is that the best solution for a fluid page and for mobile / tablet compatibility?

Comment: @mustafaulgey No it's absolutely not the best answer. I wasn't sure what he was trying to do. If this is a school project or a static website it will work fine. If he is trying to build a chemistry website then I can provide a better answer. But because he didn't really specify I just went with what I thought it looked like. For future reference when I post an answer on stack overflow should I post the best answer or the one that solves the problem?